# 504 Gateway Time-out | After submit form to mail

Tags: laravel, forms, email, smtp, submit

I get this error when I submit my Form, `504 Gateway Time-out`

I don't know why, when I tested my mail with mailtrap.io it worked, but when i used my host settings, it gives me an error

this is my Mail controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class Contactmail extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);
        Mail::to('myemail@email.com')->send(new \App\Mail\Contactmail($data));
        return redirect('contact')
            ->with('message', 'Thanks for your message. We'll be in touch.');
    }
}
```

and the view blade is

```
@component('mail::message')
    # Thank you for your message

    <strong>Name</strong> {{ $data['name'] }}
    <strong>Email</strong> {{ $data['email'] }}
    <strong>Message</strong> {{ $data['message'] }}
@endcomponent
```

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing your project locally, it may be because your ISP is blocking the port.

I use tinker to do a quick and easy test and at least get a stack trace on the error or success.

Run tinker in terminal from your project path (so it loads your mail settings from your env file):

`php artisan tinker`

and then run this snippet (don't forget to update the email to send to):

```
   \Mail::raw('hello world', function($message) {
      $message->subject('Test Mail')->to('test@example.org');
   });
```

This should give you a success or at least a stack trace to further debug the issue.

As a side note, if you're using gmail to test, you may need to configuring 2FA in Gmail or set the insecure app option to send through Gmail for testing.